# Bash removes first character in for loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

I have the following code snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='\r\n'
vconsole="pts"
for entry in $(last -n 10)
do
        if [ -z $entry ]
        then
                continue
        fi
        if [ "$( echo $entry | grep -o 'pts')" == "$vconsole" ]
        then
                echo $entry
        fi
done
```

If I execute it I get:

```
oot     pts/0        85.XXX.XXX.138   F
oot     pts/0        85.XXX.XXX.138   Mo
oot     pts/1        85.XXX.XXX.138   Tue Ja
oot     pts/0        85.XXX.XXX.138   Tue Ja
```

I expected something like this:

```
root     pts/0        85.XXX.XXX.138   Fri Jan 15 11:19   still logged in
root     pts/0        85.XXX.XXX.138   Mon Jan 11 10:12 - 10:43  (00:31)
root     pts/1        85.XXX.XXX.138   Tue Jan  5 14:30 - 14:39  (00:08)
root     pts/0        85.XXX.XXX.138   Tue Jan  5 13:29 - 14:39  (01:10)
```

Why is the first Character cut of?
Additionally, why is the end cut off seemingly random?

I am running this on a `centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64`

Comment: there are quite a few issues in your original (all of which have been fixed in ilkkachu's answer). First, avoid using `for i in $(command)`, see ["Bash pitfall number 1"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Next, `grep -o 'pts'` will only ever return either the exact string `pts` or nothing. So  since `vconsole="pts"`, the `"$( echo $entry | grep -o 'pts')" == "$vconsole" ` is pointless and could be written as `echo $entry | grep 'pts'`. Neither is what you want, as ilkkachu explained, but still.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
IFS='\r\n'
```

This sets `IFS` to `<backslash><letter r><backslash><letter n>`, so the `r` in "root" and "Fri", and the `n` in "Mon" and "Jan" act as separators.  You meant to use the ANSI C-quoting, `$'...'`, which turns the backslash escapes to the actual control characters CR and LR, i.e.:

```
IFS=$'\r\n'
```

---

Note that you could also use

```
if [[ $entry = *pts* ]]; then...
```

to look for the string, but both that and the `echo | grep` would also match e.g. fields where `pts` is part of the username.

To avoid that, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
last -n 10 | while read -r line; do
    read -r  user term whatever <<< "$line"
    if [[ $term = *pts* ]]; then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```